# Dealing with null values in @DBLookup

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

I have a domino view with an amount column but some values are empty...and need to be.  The problem is that the @Sum works fine until I have an empty value then it stops summing.

eg: if the values are 5,5,"" and 5 I get a sum of 10 and not 15.

I've traced the problem to the @DbLookup which is that it stops building the return array when it encounters a blank value.  There is no built in method of dealing with null values.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_wpdr_atfunctions_dblookup_r.html

To make things harder, @dbLookup returns a string if only one is found or an array if more than one are found.  If the values are 5,5,"" and 5 it returns an array of 2 values.

```
var alloc = @Sum(@DbLookup(@DbName(), "SubForms",MainFrmID , "ca_ca_ca_ca_amount"));
if (isNaN(alloc)){
    return "$0.00";
}else{
    return "$" + alloc.toFixed(2);
}
```

Can anyone help me refactor the @sum or @DbLookup to allow for empty values?  Unfortunately I cannot define any new functions for this solution. The environment is locked down tightly.    With a list of values of 5,5,"" and 5 I need a sum of 15.

Comment: Need to be empty? You can't change the view column formula to @If(@IsNumber(MyField);MyField;0)?  How about adding another hidden view with the same selection formula and key, but using that for the column formula?

Answer (score 1):

I would try @Sum(@TextToNumber(@Trim(@Text(@DbLookup(...)))))

Answer (score 0):

I would try 
@Sum( @Transform( @Dblookup ( ....

Comment: Thanks Werner, I gave that a go but @Transform not found.  I believe (i'm new to this) that we can only call functions that are greenlighted by admin. 
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=154: [ReferenceError] '@Transform' not found
   at [/xpCommon.js.jss].xpSetV1ComputedFields()
Any other ideas?

Comment: If '@DbLookup' indeed truncates the returned array, then '@Transform' wouldn't help anyway, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If @DbLookup does not do what you need, you could always iterate over documents or view entries to build the sum.

The flow would be roughly like this:
1. Get a handle to the current database.
2. Get a handle to the "SubForms" view.
3a. Get a view entry collection using using getAllEntriesByKey() with MainFrmID as key, if a view column exists that displays the values you need.
--OR--
3b. Get a document collection using getAllDocumentsByKey() with MainFrmID as key, if no view column exists that displays the values you need.
4. Iterate over the collection to sum up values, using getColumnValues().get(columnNumber) to access the value from each view entry, or getItemValueDouble(fieldName) to access the value from each document.

That way you can easily detect null values and discard them.